# How to loop posts in jquery tabs?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I need some help adding posts on blog page in wordpress, I want them to loop in both sidebar and jquery tabs I want to make. That would look like this

http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/4872/screenshotdu.png

The problem are these tabs. I can add loop in sidebar, but how to make (eg. last 3 posts) also appear in this jquery box?

I saw couple of plugins, including WP UI that makes this tabs awesome BUT I don't know how implement them into wordpress template file, loop.php. They didn't mention any tags or something I could use.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check out PHP for this rather than jQuery.

You can loop through a PHP array using `foreach` and can look at what is inside an array using `print_r()`.

If you have already got one of parts working, could you show that code and then we can help you duplicate it.

Comment: that's ok, but how to display this jquery box in the first place, because plugins offer adding it through admin panel in post editor. I don't need single post to do this, I need jquery hardcoded into template file and looping posts is easer part

Comment: `http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/` this may be what you need. I am struggling to understand what you require.